# How can I get this two functions into one

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have made some code in c#. I am currently developing a Gameserver so I have a function to update fields in the database. I also have a function to update the player-cash, but its like almost the same code. So my question is, do you guys have an idea to put this into one function?

```
   /// <summary>
    /// This function helps to update something in the dabase by an objectid
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value</param>
    /// <param name="userid"></param>
    public static void UpdateUserColByObjectId<T>(string key, T value, ObjectId objectid)
    {
        var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("_id", objectid);
        var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set(key, value);
        Usercol.UpdateOne(filter, update);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the cash in the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="player">The player</param>
    /// <param name="money">The new money he has</param>
    public static void ChangeDatabaseCash(Client player, int money)
    {
        //Create filters
        var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("_id", player.GetData("objectid"));
        var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set("cash", money);
        //Update it
        Usercol.UpdateOne(filter, update);
        //Create a log
        LogSystem.CreateLog("money", "Datbase cash changed to " + money + " player: " + player.GetData("objectid"));
        //change it in the client
        Utils.ChangeCashClient(player, money);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions are almost identical for the first 3 lines of code. Applying DRY (don't repeat yourself) principles you would call the first function in your second function instead of rewriting the filter / update / updateone part:

```
public static void ChangeDatabaseCash(Client player, int money)
{
    UpdateUserColByObjectId("cash", money, player.GetData("objectid"));

    //Create a log
    LogSystem.CreateLog("money", "Datbase cash changed to " + money + " player: " + player.GetData("objectid"));
    //change it in the client
    Utils.ChangeCashClient(player, money);
}
```